# How to query or calculate port utilization for devices registered with CUCM

Tags: soap, snmp, cisco, cucm

I need to query or calculate port utilization for various devices registered with Cisco CUCM, for example, H323 Gateway Port Utilization, FXS Port Utilization, BRI Channel Utilization etc.

Are these metrics available from CUCM? If yes, is it possible to query them using AXL? SNMP?

If the port utilization metrics are not available, how to query the total number of ports configured for each registered with CUCM device using AXL? I think I can obtain the number of currently active ports using AXL PerfmonPort service. If I find the way to query the total number of ports I can calculate the port utilization as following:

```
FXO port utilization = 100% * number of active FXO ports / total number of registered FXO port.
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are some paid products like Solarwinds that will do this for you.  I personally prefer Cacti though - it will use SNMP to poll routers, switches, and CUCM itself for data.  I'm able to use SNMP to show CUBE concurrent calls, PRI concurrent calls, CUBE transcoding and even CUCM itself.  Generally, if it's a router component, you can monitor it with SNMP.

Here is an intro to monitoring CUCM with SNMP:
https://www.ucguru.com/monitoring-callmanager/

I will say that it takes some time to get up and running correctly.  You may need different MIBs for each model router.